# Is it possible to express the output event when input events were used twice?

Tags: probability-theory, self-learning

**I have a the task:**
In shooting competitions, the shooter shoots n targets. The event $\Pi_i$, $i = 1,2,..., n$ is that the shooter misses when shooting at the $i$-th target. What is the event
$(\bar{\Pi}_2 \cap \bar{\Pi}_4) \cap (\cap_{i=1}^n \bar{\Pi}_i)$?

I have a problem with solution because one can see the $\bar{\Pi}_2$ and $\bar{\Pi}_4$ twice: in the first brakets and in second brakets too.

Is the task correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, though you may have issues for $n<4$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path, how to reformulate the task to avoid the problem?

Comment: Either by specifying that the problem is for $n\ge4$ ot by stating the desired event for the cases $n=1,2,3$.